# Select three count(*) in three tables

Tags: sql

I have 3 Tables:

1. Author

| author_id | author_name | birth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | J. K. Rowling | ** |

2. Books

| id | book_name | author_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ** | ** | 111 |

3. Songs

| id | song_name | author_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ** | ** | 111 |

I want to get results as the table below:

| author_id | name | number of books | number of songs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 132 | J. K. Rowling | 5 | 8 |

Comment: Have matching sample data and expected result.

Comment: Have a look (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)[here] so we'll be able to help.

Comment: Also, this feels like homework so [read up on how to ask a homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/2221001).

Comment: You may aggregate books/songs tables in subqueries then join to authors table. You may use correlated subqueries in the output list.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "I want to..." is not a question. Please tell us what you tried so far and where you got stuck and why.

Answer (score 1):

The column name "author_name" should be renamed in "author_id" or "fk_author_id" so that you instantly know that this colum stores a foreign key. But with your schema this should be the statement:

```
SELECT author_id, name
, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Books WHERE Author.author_id = Books.author_name) AS 
'number of books'
, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Songs WHERE Author.author_id = Songs.author_name) AS 
'number of songs'
FROM Author
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change your schema to get what u want. You just need to join the table with the same column like **author_id** with books and songs table. There is another version from @willi-jakob query

```
SELECT a.author_id, a.author_name as name,
       b.count as 'number of books', s.count as 'number of songs'
FROM authors a
LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT author_id, COUNT(author_id) FROM books GROUP BY author_id) b 
     on a.author_id = b.author_id
LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT author_id, COUNT(author_id) FROM songs GROUP BY author_id) s 
     on a.author_id = s.author_id;
```